# Quantification method for long term financial risk

Tags: variance, econometrics, expected-value, risk

I am working on a method to find a optimal allocation of money in various ways, like putting it on a savings account, investing it, paying off mortgage, etc. The scope of this method is to find a way to increase the money someone has at the start of the retirement as efficiently as possible.

For each of these methods ($m$), it is fairly easy to calculate the expected yield $\mathbb{E}[Y(m)]$. However, these solutions have varying amounts of risk attached to them. Investing is riskier than a savings account, with a higher yield in return. I am looking for a way to account for the amount of risk taken, for two reasons:

- The risk should not exceed what someone is willing and able to bear. (Risk tolerance and risk capacity)
- When we have two methods with a similar expected yield, we want to pick the one with the least amount of risk.

To correct the expected yield, I need to find some quantification of risk which we can calculate for each method. With a Google (scolar) search I stumbled upon a few measures like Value at Risk and Volatility, but their scope seems to be short-term, rather than long-term.

Is there a measure for long-term risk that I missed? Or else, is there some standard literature to read on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This precise strategy (maximize return and minimize risk) has already been described mathematically by Markowitz in his [Modern Portfolio Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory). The MPT uses volatility as a proxy for risk though, which as you point out is not ideal.

There are other approaches to the problem of choosing the best way to allocate money. For example, you can select investments with convex returns, meaning investments with big upside and limited downside (for example, stocks and stock options). As a consequence, the expected yield is guaranteed to be positive in the long run. Nassim Taleb has written [a series of books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0399590455) describing this investment philosophy.

Comment: Thanks! In my search I found many criticisms of MPT, but I'll read some more about it. Those books you linked looked interesting too.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam MPT fails as a model because it assumes that volatility is exogenous. As more and more people believe in using it to measure risk, however, it becomes more and more endogenous due to a causality loop (the allocation depends on volatility, which increasingly depends on the allocation), and the model becomes more and more inaccurate. It's actually a really interesting example of endogeneity.